# Android mediaplayer takes so much time in gingerbread

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm having problems playing audio streaming. The application has been tested with differents APIs.
The media player in gingerbread(API 10) takes about 30-40 seconds on preparing state, however on API 7 takes only about 5-10 seconds on preparing state. Anyone know how to fix it?

I have looked in differents forums but don't get an answer.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the fact that the buffering in Gingerbread is based upon fixed bytes rather than anything that has to do with the time it takes to play the stream.  If the stream is low-fidelity, it will take a very long time to buffer.  There is no fix other than to write your own streaming player.

Comment: Thanks!!! Find enclosed an example. ¿Could be ok to improve the performance?http://blog.infidian.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Find enclosed an example. ¿Could be ok to improve the performance?

http://blog.infidian.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/